# Titanium Backup cannot Backup Accounts

Tags: backup, accounts, titanium-backup

I want to move to a new phone. But Titanium Backup does not work in backing up my accounts. It always says success even though the backup is only 1KB big and has nothing in it. Is there any other app or a manual way to backup the accounts? Or has anyone a fix for Titanium?

To clearify this I'm talking about the accounts in the settings like this:
[image]

Comment: What accounts are you talking about? Google? Or...?

Comment: @beeshyams im talking about the accounts section in the settings. Yeah one example is the google account.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the https://github.com/machiav3lli/oandbackupx/ project I found out that the accounts are saved at `/data/system_ce/0/accounts_ce.db`, at least for me. I then tried, editing this file very careful, but I think there are some dependencies to other things I don't understand yet. Even with the smallest editions my phone got stuck in a bootloop. Also recovering an backup of the file, didn't fix the bootloop. I had to restore a whole nandroid data partition backup.